# In Intellij idea, how do I mark MyEnum.values() as @NonNull?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullable

Enum.values() physically can't return null (At least I can't get it to return null) but since there is no "Implementation" class for it IntelliJ won't let me mark it as @NonNull in the external annotations file.

The best I can figure out so far is to create a method like this in my enum class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("Constant Conditions")
@NonNull
public static MyEnum[] getValues()
{
    return values()
}
```

This works but is useless code and although any programmer would recognize MyEnum.values() immediately, .getValues() would force you to at least look at the javadocs to see what was going on.

Am I missing some way to tell IntelliJ that this non-method is safe?

Comment: Is IntelliJ lying to you and saying that an invocation of this method might somehow return `null`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `in the external annotations file`?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, it is.  Enable annotation based nullability checks and copy the above code to see.

Comment: @user7 IntelliJ allows for external annotations of library files because it can't determine itself If a method like String.toLowerCase() can return a null (it can't), so you alt-enter and select "Add not null annotation" and it creates an xml file with that information.

Comment: Where are you getting this annotation from again?

Comment: @Makoto IntelliJ has a list of around 4 annotations by default in settings/inspections/@NotNull/probable bugs/Nullable problems/Configure Annotations.  It's really best if you create your own and add them to this list (Which I have).

Comment: @Makoto, if you meant the external annotation file, by the way, that is set up as part of your VM settings (File/Project Structure/SDKs/Annotations/) and add a directory location for intellij to store the annotation XML files (There is actually a file for each class I believe stored in a package structure at that location)

Comment: For the second case, you can still pass null to it. Java won't complain.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn If you pass null, java will give you an empty array.  I didn't try casting the null to an array type though... Let me do that and see if it breaks...  Nope, still can't get "b" to be null.

Comment: Just as an aside on general weirdness, if you pass a single null Java gives you an empty array, if you pass 2 nulls java sends you an array of length 2 with each value being null.  In no case can I get it to return a null for the array though.

Comment: Just tested it. Got a null, as expected with `showProblem((Boolean[]) null)`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Ahh, you are probably right, teach me to test things in Groovy, the subtle differences sometimes bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Your annotation syntax is incorrect; you have placed `@NonNull` in the wrong location.

`@NonNull` is a type annotation and should be written in front of the type. It applies to the type it is written immediately before.

For backward compatibility, Java lets you write type annotations before modifiers such as `public`; this can lead to confusion.
What you wrote is equivalent to this:

`public static @NonNull MyEnum[] getValues() { ... }`

That says that `getValues()` returns a possibly-null array of non-null values.

Instead, you probably want to write

`public static MyEnum @NonNull [] getValues() { ... }`

which says that `getValues()` returns a non-null array.

Similarly, you probably want to write 
`X @NonNull [] x = X.values();`
instead of
`@NonNull X[] x = X.values();`.

Comment: The part that IntelliJ is complaining about is X.values(), it says it's nullable when it's not. Also when I try your suggested method signature IntelliJ errors with "NonNull not applicable to type use (Even though the method itself should be unnecessary, I thought I'd give it a try).  The question was, how do I annotate X.values() itself when .values isn't a method call at all, it's translated by the compiler.

Comment: OK, it seems that IntelliJ has not yet switched `@NonNull` to being a type annotation.  Thanks for the info, and sorry for the false alarm.  This answer isn't relevant until IntelliJ updates their annotations as other tools such as Eclipse already have.

Comment: NonNull Is actually my annotation, perhaps I need to clean it up (I'll look into it).  The problem is still that Intellij can't mark enum.values() as NonNull. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to mark this method as `@NotNull` because IntelliJ IDEA knows by itself that it is @NotNull. Try the following code snippet:

```
 enum X { a, b }

 public void v() {
    if (X.values() == null) {
         System.out.println("Can't happen");
    }
 }
```

IntelliJ IDEA will highlight the `==` check as "Condition is always false".

Comment: Yep, but I think the OP *want* to add `@NotNull` annotation for sake of JavaDoc. Also, if you're using another IDE (I tried NetBeans), there doesn't have do be this kind of analyzing the code.

Comment: @yole Change your method contents to "@NonNull X[] x = X.values();" and watch intellij complain.  It absolutely shouldn't because your code is correct, but it does. (Assuming that you have null annotations enabled)